# SOAP client method with parameter returns null eventhough there is data

Tags: php, xml, soap

The SOAP server I call has two functions

> GetUserInfo and
>   GetAllUserInfo

the client calls the second function perfectly and displays all users. But the first function returns a null. I know it has something to do with the parameters, so I have tried a number of possible ways, still nothing. Here is the xml of soap and the function I used.

1.**GetUserInfo**

**Request Xml:**

```
<GetUserInfo>
 <ArgComKey xsi:type="xsd:integer”>ComKey</ArgComKey>
    <Arg>
      <PIN xsi:type="xsd:integer”>Job Number</PIN>
    </Arg>
</GetUserInfo>
```

**Response Xml:**

```
<GetUserInfoResponse>
  <Row>
   <PIN>XXXXX</PIN>
   <Name>XXXX</Name>
   <Password>XXX</Password>
```

**2.GetAllUserInfo ***

**Request Xml:**

```
<GetAllUserInfo>
   <ArgComKey xsi:type="xsd:integer”>ComKey</ArgComKey>
</GetAllUserInfo>
```

**Response Xml:**

```
<GetAllUserInfoResponse>
  <Row>
    <PIN>XXXXX</PIN>
    <Name>XXXX</Name>
    <Password>XXX</Password>
    < Group>X</ Group>
```

And here is the code I wrote for the client I use to get a specific user and all users.

```
try {
        $opts = array('location' => 'http://192.168.0.201/iWsService',
                       'uri'      => 'iWsService');
        $client = new \SOAPClient(null, $opts);
        $attendance = $client->__soapCall('GetUserInfo', array('PIN'=> 2));
        var_dump($attendance);
    } catch (SOAPFault $exception) {
        print $exception;
    }
```

When I called GetAllUserInfo with a parameter of empty array() it returns all the users. Including a user with PIN = 2. But the GetUserInfo method returns null. Am I missing something when I called the GetUserInfo method?

Comment: You have to pass parameters to `GetUserInfo` which match the WSDL file, and it appears ypu are not doing this.  Please give us a link to your WSDL file.

Comment: I am trying to upload the file so I can share it with you but its taking longer than I hoped. But I have put the execrept of the file in the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Here is a link to the document https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1CCLsJa7-0YeWxTY1dNT2NLR2s&authuser=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the correct SOAP call for `GetUserInfo`, you will need to know 2 parameters: the `ComKey` and the `PIN`.  In my SOAP call below, I assume that the `ComKey` is `12345`, but you will have to replace this value with something meaningful.  Try using the following code:

```
try {
    $opts = array('location' => 'http://192.168.0.201/iWsService',
                  'uri'      => 'iWsService');
    $client = new \SOAPClient(null, $opts);
    $attendance = $client->__soapCall('GetUserInfo', array('ArgComKey'=>12345,
                                                           'Arg' => array('PIN' => 2)));
    var_dump($attendance);
} catch (SOAPFault $exception) {
    print $exception;
}
```

Here I am trying to match the XML format for the `GetUserInfo` request as closely as possible.